# Django: It takes a long time to filter the m2m model from the m2m-connected model by specifying the field values of the m2m model

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

The m2m through table has about 1.4 million rows.

The slowdown is probably due to the large number of rows,
but I'm sure I'm writing the queryset correctly.
What do you think is the cause?

It will take about 400-1000ms.

If you do filter by pk instead of name, it will not be that slow.

```py
# models.py
class Tag(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


class Video(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    thumbnail_url = models.URLField(max_length=1000)
    preview_url = models.URLField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    embed_url = models.URLField(max_length=1000)
    sources = models.ManyToManyField(Source)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, db_index=True)
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, db_index=True)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    published_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

```py
Video.objects.filter(tags__name='word').only('id').order_by('-published_at');
```

Query issued

```sql
SELECT "videos_video"."id"
FROM "videos_video"
INNER JOIN "videos_video_tags" ON ("videos_video"."id" = "videos_video_tags"."video_id")
INNER JOIN "videos_tag" ON ("videos_video_tags"."tag_id" = "videos_tag"."id")
WHERE "videos_tag"."name" = 'word'
ORDER BY "videos_video"."published_at" DESC;
```

EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)

```
                                                                                                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                                                               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=4225.63..4226.23 rows=241 width=24) (actual time=456.321..473.827 rows=135178 loops=1)
   Output: videos_video.id, videos_video.published_at
   Sort Key: videos_video.published_at DESC
   Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4504kB
   Buffers: shared hit=540568 read=11368, temp read=563 written=566
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=20.45..4216.10 rows=241 width=24) (actual time=5.538..398.841 rows=135178 loops=1)
         Output: videos_video.id, videos_video.published_at
         Inner Unique: true
         Buffers: shared hit=540568 read=11368
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=20.02..4102.13 rows=241 width=16) (actual time=5.513..76.291 rows=135178 loops=1)
               Output: videos_video_tags.video_id
               Buffers: shared hit=2 read=11222
               ->  Index Scan using videos_tag_name_620230b0_like on public.videos_tag  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.020..0.022 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Output: videos_tag.id, videos_tag.name, videos_tag.is_actress, videos_tag.created_at
                     Index Cond: ((videos_tag.name)::text = 'word'::text)
                     Buffers: shared hit=1 read=2
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.videos_video_tags  (cost=19.74..4079.23 rows=1460 width=32) (actual time=5.489..62.122 rows=135178 loops=1)
                     Output: videos_video_tags.id, videos_video_tags.video_id, videos_video_tags.tag_id
                     Recheck Cond: (videos_video_tags.tag_id = videos_tag.id)
                     Heap Blocks: exact=11112
                     Buffers: shared hit=1 read=11220
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on videos_video_tags_tag_id_2673cfc8  (cost=0.00..19.38 rows=1460 width=0) (actual time=4.215..4.215 rows=135178 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: (videos_video_tags.tag_id = videos_tag.id)
                           Buffers: shared hit=1 read=108
         ->  Index Scan using videos_video_pkey on public.videos_video  (cost=0.42..0.47 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=135178)
               Output: videos_video.id, videos_video.title, videos_video.thumbnail_url, videos_video.preview_url, videos_video.embed_url, videos_video.duration, videos_video.views, videos_video.is_public, videos_video.published_at, videos_video.created_at, videos_video.updated_at
               Index Cond: (videos_video.id = videos_video_tags.video_id)
               Buffers: shared hit=540566 read=146
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=33 read=13
 Planning Time: 0.991 ms
 Execution Time: 481.274 ms
(32 rows)

Time: 482.869 ms
```

Comment: Is something like this quicker? `Tag.objects.get(name='word').video_set.order_by('-published_at')`

Comment: Oh! This works pretty fast!!!! Thank you very much. Why does this work so fast?

Comment: Because you query across all three tables in the worst case you create a JOIN with 1.4 million rows and then search all those rows for your results. Because I split the query up you only get a single row from the tags table the join is massively reduced, I think postgres also has an easier time figuring out which indexes to use when the query is only filtering and joining on PKs and FKs

Comment: I see, this is probably the reason for the other slow queries through m2m. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I posted a question similar to this one, and I hope you can answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the method described in Iain Shelvington's comment.

```py
Tag.objects.get(name='word').video_set.order_by('-published_at')
```

Comment: But, what query did this translate into?

Answer (score 0):

Did your database got EXACTLY thoses indexes :

1. "videos_tag" ("name", "id")
2. "videos_video_tags" ("tag_id", "video_id")
3. "videos_video" ("id", "published_at")

If not, try it !